# ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error with git push

Tags: git

I committed some local changes and attempted to push them to a remote branch.

However, my changes were rejected for some reason.

```
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://app/GIT/app'
```

when I run `git status`, I see this message:

```
On branch master

Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I have attempted do the following:

```
git push origin master
```

but the changes are also rejected.

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://app/GIT/app'
```

Also, tried -

```
`git reset --hard origin/master`  and made those changes again and pushed them to get rejected.
```

What else I might try?

Comment: Try a `git fetch` first, followed by `git rebase`/`git merge`/`git reset`/etc.  That error usually indicates that your local branch is out-of-sync and missing commits from origin.

Comment: if I do `git fetch`, followed by `git reset/rebase`, wouldn't I lose my commits/local changes? @0x5453

Comment: Fetching and Rebasing will not make you lose your local changes. You may have to resolve a merge conflict but that's all.

Comment: That didn't work. `git fetch` -> `git rebase` -> `git commit` -> `git push branch master`. Still getting the same error.

Comment: @AndrewFan when I do `git pull`, it says: Already up to date. So, I guess local branch is in sync with origin/master?

Comment: What server are you pushing your work to ? It says "**pre-receive hook declined**", which means that it's not a Git problemn but some third-party hook installed on server-side rejected your submission. It's usually there to enforce some custom policies, but sometimes it may be a bug too. If you're using Github, Gitlab or Atlassian, visit your user console from their website. If this is your company's server and you have an access to it, try to check out the logs from there.

Comment: Yeah, I think so too. Looks like a server-side issue vs git. I do not have access to the server or logs.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to change branch permission in Repo settings. for example in `BitBucket` you can find it in `Project settings` ->  `Branch permissions`. then add permission to change branches such as develop or master or other branches to be allowed to modified by the user.